# Reading size of a gui element before it is drawn to the screen in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, size

I am developing for android and I need to read the final width and height of a gui element before it is drawn to the screen. Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size is only known after the view has been measured. If you want to find out about its size as early as possible, you can use a ViewTreeObserver.

```
private View view; // the view whose size you want to know

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSatet) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.whatever);
    view = findViewById(...);

    final ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // if you only need the size once, unregister this listener
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            // here you can call view.getWidth() and view.getHeight()
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if your view is a custom View, you can override [`onSizeChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))